# How to check if any of a series of checkboxes are checked in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a series of checkboxes that I populate using a foreach loop (php).  The code looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="artist_group[]" id="{{$fb_data['fbid']}}" class="input-hidden" data-name="{{$fb_data['name']}}" value="{{$fb_data['fbid']}}" style="display:none;"  />
        <label for="{{$fb_data['fbid']}}">
        <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{$fb_data['fbid']}}/picture?width=200&height=200" width="140" height="140" alt="{{$fb_data['name']}}"/>
        <article class="artistName">{{$fb_data['name']}}</article>
        </label>
```

What I would like to do is check if any of the checkboxes are checked using javascript.  However, I can't do this using the `"getElementById"` because I want each checkbox to have a unique id (so I can pull the data).  I have the name of the checkbox group as an array, so I can send all of the checked boxes to my backend.  Can I do the following?:

```
if (document.getElementByName('artist_group').checked) {
            alert("checked");
        }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In jQuery: Use a selector that catches all the relevant checkboxes, combine that with the `:checked` selector, and then look at the `length` of the jQuery object you get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged jQuery in your question as well, you can use jQuery's $.each.

Just select the elements by the class and not id.

```
$('.input-hidden').each(function() {
  //this will iterate through all checkboxes
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {//Per @Felix's comment, this.checked is a more native way of doing it, I personally just prefer to use $(this) when I'm in jQuery context, to be consistent. Using this.checked is quicker though.
    //this will apply just to the checked checkboxes
   }
});
```

You can also get ONLY the selected checkboxes by:

```
$('input:checked').each(function() {
   //this will only apply to selected checkboxes
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Syntax highlighting is wrong, as you're missing a closing `'` in the first line. :)

Comment: I also believe you are missing a `(` after `$` in the `if` statement. Note that it's much more appropriate to write `if (this.checked)` though.

Comment: Yupp, second line has to be `if ($(this).is(':checked')) {`

Comment: @FelixKling I somehow prefer to use $(this) to be consistent with jQuery syntax...but I see your point.

Answer (score 2):

You have iterate over the checkboxes and test whether any of them is checked or not. Note that the method name is *`getElementsByName`* (Elements with s):

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByName('artist_group[]');
var checked = false;
for (var i = 0, l = boxes.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (boxes[i].checked) {
        checked = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you are not opposed to newer JavaScript methods, you can also use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var checked = Array.prototype.some.call(boxes, function(input) {
    return input.checked;
});
```

With jQuery, it's even simpler:

```
var checked = $('input[name="artist_group[]"]:checked').length > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you also used the jQuery tag for your question: IF you're using jQuery anyway (don't just add it only for this task, that's an overkill!):

```
if ( ! $('input[name="artist_group"]').is(':not(:checked)') ) {
   // all are selected
}
```